# Real time data streaming should change UI based on last received time

Tags: javascript, angularjs, real-time

I have real time data coming in, based on which I have to change indicator in UI. Meaning if I don't receive data in the last 30 sec , the indicator should turn red. If data is received before thirty 30 sec, it should be green. Note that data comes into the function one after the other. The indicator should change for each data(curveName) in this case.

I have used $timeout and $interval, but unable to crack the problem. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can maybe add in your controller something like:

```
var timer,
    timeLimit = 30000; //30s limit

function onDataReceived(data) {
  //  cancel previous timer
  if(timer) $timeout.cancel(timer);

  // assuming data is good set indicator to green
  $scope.indicator = "green";

  // set 30s timer for indicator to go red
  timer = $timeout(function(){
    $scope.indicator = "red";
  }, timeLimit);
}
```

Depending on how the data is received and your application structure, you can consider using something like:

```
$scope.$watch('data', onDataReceived);
```

Comment: This is the exact thing I tried without the watch. But won't other data be coming in, when it is waiting 30 sec. The indicator should be for each curve.

Comment: What happens with this is it set red for the last data(curve) it has received, while I have to make for each data.

Comment: That’s why in the code above I cancel the timer and set a new 30s timer every time new data coming in.  Can you provide some sample code and structure of your data? It’s very difficult to understand the context of what you are describing like “curve” or how the data coming in

Comment: I will be able to provide the code on Monday. For now I would like to tell my $timeout.cancel() is after scope.indicator = green. Could this be a reason?

Comment: Data which is coming is curves(app specific) which I am showing in an abn-tree with the last level as the curve. Now there could be multiple tree with same or different curves. There would be indicator on each curve. And each should behave like told.